# Sumar o restar 1 en jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estoy intentando sumar o restar 1 en un input pero no lo termino de conseguir.
el codigo que tengo es este:

```
onclick="$('#StockPagina').val($('#StockPagina').val()+1).change()"
```

esto me cambia el valor del input StockPagina pero me añade un 1 al final en vez de sumar uno con lo que según le voy dando en vez de poner 1,2,3,4 me pone 01,011,0111

¿no puedo hacer que simplemente sume uno al valor que hay?
¿Existe algo tipo el ++ de php?
¿si existe algo tipo ++ existe tambien el -- para restar?

Muchas gracias por vuestra ayuda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te falta convertir el valor de tu `input` a número para poder ejecutar en él operaciones matemáticas, esto lo logras con la función [Number](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_number.asp) de **JavaScript**

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="StockPagina">
<button onclick="$('#StockPagina').val(Number($('#StockPagina').val()) + 1).change()">Sumar</button>
```

Answer (score 4):

Prueba con:

```
onclick="$('#StockPagina').val(Number( $('#StockPagina').val() ) + 1).change()"
```

Recuerda que el valor de los *input* es **una cadena**; tenemos que convertirla en número antes de sumar; si no lo hacemos, concatena.

Comment: Genial :) Funciona perfectamente

Comment: Considera marcar la respuesta correcta Killpe

Comment: @Killpe: Es cierto lo que dice Eduardo Sebastian. Si te sirvio la respuesta, marcala como que es la solucion a tu pregunta y asi ahorrarle tiempo a personas que estan dispuestas a ayudar. Gracias.

Comment: Hola @IsaacVega es que me respondieron antes de que la web permitiese marcar respuesta correcta. Al intentar darle me decía que tenía que esperar y ya se me fue el santo al cielo.